# How to serve django static files through nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx

So far Nginx serves my django content not static files (css, js, images ) when `DUBUG = False`

before that i collected all static files and placed in outside of the project directory

```
live
 --Project
 --staticfiles
```

**Error :**

```
2015/01/23 10:26:29 [error] 2599#0: *42 open() "/home/dev_21six_com/live/staticfiles/images/favicon.ico" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 182.74.206.202, server: example.com, request: "GET /static/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

**Permission :**

```
[root@instance-4 live]# ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwx.  5 root          root            51 Jan 20 05:35 .
drwxrwxrwx. 11 user          user          4096 Jan  7 10:51 ..
drwxrwxrwx.  9 root          root          4096 Jan 20 05:35 Project
drwxrwxrwx.  2 root          root            22 Jan 13 07:07 logs
drwxrwxrwx.  8 user          user            93 Jan 12 12:55 staticfiles
```

*nginx.conf*

```
user user;
```

*sites-available/example.com*

```
upstream test {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
        keepalive 500;
}

server {

    listen   80;
    server_name example.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    location /static/ {
       alias   /home/user/live/staticfiles/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
         proxy_pass http://test;
         break;
    }

    }
}
```

**Updated:**

```
[root@instance-4 nginx]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

Comment: Two questions: are you running with SELinux enabled and what are the permissions on the ico file itself (can e.g. the user access that file)

Comment: @Foon I updated question with SElinux. That files is `user` only though i haven't checked with user login...!

Comment: Were you able to run with *SELinux* and serve static files from `Nginx`?  I currently having the same issue and SELinux is making all Nginx static files 403 permission denied.